# Is there any way to manipulate scrollbar using javascript in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, api, firefox, scrollbar, default

I am writing a UserChromeJS script (If you don't know what UserChromeJS is, please take a look at http://userchromejs.mozdev.org/)that turns the scrollbar into a floating one.

Link to my script: https://github.com/nightson/userChromeJS/blob/master/FloatingScrollbar.uc.js

What I want to do next is to make the scrollbar auto-hidden when not scrolling. But this is hard to achieve without being able to add/remove class to/from the scrollbar. I tried methods like querySelector and getAnonymousElementByAttribute without success. Could anyone help me?

p.s: I don't want to hide the default scrollbar and create a new one, so please don't suggest solutions like jscrollpane.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to do next is to make the scrollbar auto-hidden when not scrolling.

No, this has two issues:

- The scrollbar will be hidden by default, since not scrolling is the default state
- The `onscroll` event will never be triggered, since the scrollbar is hidden by default